# Is there a way to make a wrapper function for renderUI in Shiny (R)?

Tags: r, shiny, renderui

I need to use `renderUI` to create multiple input options based on another input value. I want to wrap everything inside `renderUI` as a function so I can apply this to many similar inputs. Here is a simplified example (which is working for me, but I don't want to repeat the `renderUI` part many times, because I have many other inputs like the `i1`):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        selectInput(
            inputId = 'i1',
            label = 'choice 1',
            choices = list(5, 10)
        ),
        uiOutput('o1')
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$o1 <- renderUI(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput(
                inputId = 's1',
                label = 'slider 1',
                min = 0, max = as.numeric(input$i1) * 10,
                value = 0.5
            ),
            sliderInput(
                inputId = 's2',
                label = 'slider 2',
                min = 0, max = as.numeric(input$i1) * 100,
                value = 0.5
            )
        )
    )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is that when I tried to wrap it into a function, the output created by `renderUI` stops to update when I change the input value. Here is the code that doesn't work for me:

```
library(shiny)
renderUI_warpper <- function(i){
    renderUI(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput(
                inputId = 's1',
                label = 'slider 1',
                min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 10,
                value = 0.5
            ),
            sliderInput(
                inputId = 's2',
                label = 'slider 2',
                min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 100,
                value = 0.5
            )
        )
    )
}
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        selectInput(
            inputId = 'i1',
            label = 'choice 1',
            choices = list(5, 10)
        ),
        uiOutput('o1')
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$o1 <- renderUI_warpper(input$i1)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible alternative:

```
library(shiny)

create_sliders <- function(i) {
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "s1",
        label = "slider 1",
        min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 10,
        value = 0.5
      ),
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "s2",
        label = "slider 2",
        min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 100,
        value = 0.5
      )
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "i1",
      label = "choice 1",
      choices = list(5, 10)
    ),
    uiOutput("o1")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$o1 <- renderUI({
    create_sliders(input$i1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. This indeed worked for me. I changed the function by moving `renderUI` out and it updated every time I changed the input or when a reactive value for the function changed.

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't see the point to do this because even you move that part to a function, you still have to define each `sliderInput`, here is one way to do it.

The point is you should wrap the Input instead of `renderUI`, because you need reactive expressions to be able to update input and reactive only works within another reactive or `render*` functions

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(
      inputId = 'i1',
      label = 'choice 1',
      choices = list(5, 10)
    ),
    uiOutput('o1')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  wrapper <- reactive({
    function(i){
      fluidRow(
        sliderInput(
          inputId = 's1',
          label = 'slider 1',
          min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 10,
          value = 0.5
        ),
        sliderInput(
          inputId = 's2',
          label = 'slider 2',
          min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 100,
          value = 0.5
        )
      )
      }
  })
  output$o1 <- renderUI(wrapper()(input$i1))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can declare the function outside the server and then call it with `input$i1` as an argument. `create_sliders <- function(i){
  fluidRow(
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 's1',
      label = 'slider 1',
      min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 10,
      value = 0.5
    ),
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 's2',
      label = 'slider 2',
      min = 0, max = as.numeric(i) * 100,
      value = 0.5
    )
  )
}`

Comment: Inside the server: `output$o1 <- renderUI({
    create_sliders(input$i1)
  })`

Comment: @jpdugo17 I am afraid that is equivalent to OP's proposal and will not update the scale when selectInput changes, since there is no reactive around `create_sliders`

Comment: This worked for me and I like this idea: making the `warpper` a reactive function inside the server.
Now I wonder why @jpdugo17's method worked for me as well. Based on @englealuze' comments it shouldn't have worked...

Comment: @coffee just tested that. it indeed works. I guess the `renderUI({ })` did the job to add some reactive features to a normal function such like `create_sliders`